# What do I need to do the following things with an arduino?

Tags: arduino

I need to do the following with an arduino board:

- Drive something at a power higher than that of the usb, like max 50W. I guess I have to use analog output and then amplify the signal somehow, but I don't know how.
- Do the opposite too, I mean safely measure a signal if it is even at 50W, without frying the arduino in the process.

As you can guess I'm a newbye, so please be patient.

Comment: 50 Watts (W) or Volts (V)? If you really meant Watts, what is the voltage range of the analog output you want to produce? What is the voltage level of the signal you are sensing?

Comment: 50W, for the voltage say 12V. Anyway I just wanted to know how to drive a device that I can't drive with usb power

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your question:  Are you using DC or AC? If it's AC, things are potentially a modest amount more complicated, and I have little experience in that world so I'll defer from commenting much further, on any AC specifics, other than mentioning Triacs

That said, in principle, there are a few ways to control a higher-current / higher-voltage load from an Arduino.

Note that in all the scenarios I'm describing here, I'm talking about using an independent power supply to power the load.

1. use a "power transistor."  You'd probably want a MOSFET or an IGBT, rated for the voltage / current you're trying to control.  For MOSFETs, you'll probably want to look for a "logic level" MOSFET where the gate can be driven fully on by the 5 volts from an Arduino digital pin.  If you use an IGBT or an non-logic-level MOSFET you'll need additional circuitry to drive 10-12 volts (usually) to the gate.  They make "MOSFET Driver" ICs that are purpose built for this, but you can also roll your own driver (of sorts) a couple of different ways.  I've gotten good results using a quad voltage comparator IC.
2. Use a (mechanical) relay.  You'll have to poke around the parts catalogs to find a relay that can be controlled by an Arduino, or - again - you'll need some additional circuitry between the Arduino and the relay.
3. Use a solid-state relay (SSR).
4. If you're doing AC, you'll probably want a Triac.

Some other considerations:  You might want an optoisolator between your arduino and ANY of these devices.  It's not strictly required, but it will help protect your Arduino from damage.

IF your load circuit is DC, you can (usually) just join the ground of the power supply that's driving your load and the ground on your Arduino.  This makes wiring things up a bit simpler, but there is some small risk associated with ground loops. This is not a concern if you use an optoisolator.

If you're doing AC,  you absolutely can't just connect the two circuits together.

If your load is inductive (like, say, a motor) there are additional concerns regarding "inductive kickback."  Read up on that before you start switching motors on and off.

As for measuring.. are you trying to measure voltage or current (amperage) or both?  For current, you could possibly use a hall effect sensor, or an inductive current sensor.  I've never tried measuring voltage like that, but there's a long thread on the old Arduino forum talking about this stuff:

http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1205745528

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Of course I was talking about DC! Is MOSFET ok for analog driving too?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you may have volts and watts mixed up. To clear things up can you please update your question with:

- What you want to drive and its rated voltage/current (if not sure a link to the manual or datasheet would do)
- What signal you wish to measure (what's it from? what voltage/current/frequency?)

Assuming you don't have voltage/watts mixed up, then the answer to the first question is you would need an external power supply.
One USB port supplies 5V at 500mA maximum. 5V x 0.5A = 2.5W.
Depending on what you are driving the solutions vary, so I'll wait until more info is available to go into more detail.

Assuming the same for the second question, you would need to measure voltage and current (possibly phase if AC) and perform the necessary calculations to get power. Again, depending on the voltage/current levels and whether the signal measured is AC/DC, shares ground with the Arduino, etc, the solution will vary. Whatever the levels, it will be quite possible to do this without damaging the Arduino.